# Unable to update the RecyclerView instantly after capturing image from camera

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am new to RecyclerViews. My aim is to capture the image by camera using a button and displaying it in recyclerview whenever i capture the image. The problem is when i capture image for the first time, it does not appear in recyclerview. The second time i take picture, it then show the previous image stored.I think i am not able to use notifyDataSetChanged() properly. Please help,I am stuck in this.

**Main Activity:-**

```
package com.example.cold.recyclerexample;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
MyAdapter myAdapter;
File downLoadFolder;
private ArrayList<Photos> photoData = new ArrayList<>();
private Uri photoUri;
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        myAdapter=new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, getData());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        Button cameraButton = findViewById(R.id.camera_button);
        cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                captureImage();
                myAdapter=new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, getData());
                recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
    }

    private ArrayList<Photos> getData() {

        downLoadFolder = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        Photos ph;
        if (downLoadFolder.exists()) {
            File[] files = downLoadFolder.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                File file = files[i];
                ph = new Photos();
                ph.setMedicineName("abcd");
                ph.setMedicineAvailable("32");
                ph.setUri(Uri.fromFile(file));
                photoData.add(ph);
            }
        }
        return photoData;

    }
    private File createImageFile ()
    {
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
File image = new File(downLoadFolder, imageFileName);
return image;
}
    private void captureImage() {
        Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePicture.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File photoFile = null;
            photoFile = createImageFile();
            if (photoFile != null) {
               photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "com.example.cold.recyclerexample.fileprovider", photoFile);
               takePicture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
                startActivityForResult(takePicture, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}
}}
}
```

**MyAdpter.class:-**

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {
Context c;
ArrayList<Photos> photoDataList;
public MyAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Photos> photoDataList) {
        this.c = c;
        this.photoDataList = photoDataList;
    }
@NonNull
 @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v= LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.layout_to_inflate,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
Photos photos=photoDataList.get(position);
holder.remaining.setText(photos.getMedicineName());
holder.remaining.setText(photos.getMedicineAvailable());
        Picasso.get().load(photos.getUri()).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.myImage);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return photoDataList.size();
    }

}
```

**MyViewHolder.class**

```
  package com.example.cold.recyclerexample;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
TextView medicineName;
TextView remaining;
ImageView myImage;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
medicineName=itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
remaining=itemView.findViewById(R.id.remaining);
myImage=itemView.findViewById(R.id.nImageView);

    }

}
```

**Photos.class**

```
package com.example.cold.recyclerexample;

import android.net.Uri;

public class Photos {
    private String medicineName;
    private String medicineAvailable;

    public Uri getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public void setUri(Uri uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    private Uri uri;

    public void setMedicineName(String medicineName) {
        this.medicineName = medicineName;
    }

    public void setMedicineAvailable(String medicineAvailable) {
        this.medicineAvailable = medicineAvailable;
    }

    public String getMedicineName() {
        return medicineName;
    }

    public String getMedicineAvailable() {
        return medicineAvailable;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait the result of the activity before calling                 recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
you have to implement onActivityResult inside your activity
check this: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Comment: **I added this code for checking onActivityResult in my activity, but i got null point error " Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getData()' on a null object reference"**                                  
 `@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        {
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
    Log.e("URI", String.valueOf(data.getData()));
            }
        }

    }`